# Prove that the number of ordered lists without repeats that can be constructed from an $n$-set is very nearly $n!e$. The lists can be of any length.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I know the ordered list with repeat with any length should be 
$n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots3.2.1$
but where $e$ comes form?

The chapter that has this problem mention Stirling formula, is it related with this proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is exactly
$$n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}$$
since $n!/k!$ is the number of lists of length $n-k$ without repeats.
Of course the sum tends rapidly to $e$.